# Can I define an option in a Yeoman subgenerator, and then reference that option from the base generator?

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I have an EJS template file that is located in the base generator, but needs to be able to read options from both the base generator and the subgenerator.

### Base Generator

```
module.exports = generators.Base.extend({
  constructor: function() {
    generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);

    this.option('option1');
  },

  initializing: function() {
    this.composeWith('base:sub-gen', this.options, {
      local: require.resolve('../sub-gen'),
      link: 'strong'
      });
  }
});
```

### Subgenerator

```
module.exports = generators.Base.extend({
  constructor: function() {
    generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);

    this.option('option2');
  },
});
```

### Template

```
Base generator option: <%=this.options.option1 %>
Sub-generator option: <%=this.options.option2 %>
```

Is there any way to reference the sub-generator options from my ejs template?
Barring that, how else can I make sure that my base generator and my sub-generator all have access to the same list of options? Maybe it's possible using `.yo-rc.json`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on it some more, I found a solution:

1. In both generators, set the configs in the `configuring` step, but read them in the `default` step.
2. After reading the configs with `this.config.get('key')` or `this.config.getAll()`, save them as a property of the generator you want to use them in: `this.imports = this.config.get('option-name')`.

## Example:

### Base Generator

```
module.exports = generators.Base.extend({
  constructor: function() {
    generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);

    this.option('option1');
  },

  initializing: function() {
    this.composeWith('base:sub-gen', this.options, {
      local: require.resolve('../sub-gen'),
      link: 'strong'
      });
  },

  configuring: function () {
    let configs = {
      option1: option1
    };

    this.config.set(configs);
  },

    default: function() {
        let config = this.config.getAll()
        this.imports = this.config.get('subGenOptions');
    },
});
```

### Subgenerator

```
module.exports = generators.Base.extend({
  constructor: function() {
    generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);

    this.option('option2');
  },
  configuring: function() {
    let configs = {
        subGenOptions: {
            option2: this.options.option2
        }
    }

    this.config.set(configs)
  },
});
```

### Template *(in base generator)*

```
Base generator option: <%=options.option1 %>
Sub-generator option: <%=imports.option2 %>
```